# Listen to keyboard press notifications

Tags: ios, swift

I have subclassed `UIApplication` and managed to set up a listener for the `sendEvent` function. How can I get a notification when the user touches a certain button on the keyboard? I can get the touch location in `sendEvent`, is it possible to convert this location to the chosen character?

```
import Foundation 
import UIKit

    @objc(Scale) class Scale: UIApplication {

        override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent ) {
            if event.type != .touches {
                super.sendEvent(event)
                return
            }

            if let touches2 = event.allTouches {
                for touch in touches2.enumerated() {
                    if(touch.element.view == ViewController.self().forceLabel ){
                        print("text touched ")
                    }
                    if(touch.element.phase == UITouchPhase.began ) {
                        //Stuff
                        //print("=====================================")
                        //print (touch.element.view as Any)
                        print("**********************")
                        print(touch.element.location(in: touches2.first?.view))
                        print("**********************") 
                    }
                    if(touch.element.phase == UITouchPhase.ended) {
                        //Stuff
                        print(";")
                    }
                    //print(touch.element.phase )
                }
                if let touch = touches2.first {  

                }
            }
            super.sendEvent(event)
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Your English sentences are terribly broken without even separating them with the period.  I don't know what you mean by subclassing your iOS application.

Comment: Such helpfulness, much constructive, very wow. @ElTomato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i mange to get the key by converting the location to key 
this method will only work for i phone 7 plus with the default keyboard 
and is not perfect some times it return the wrong key

```
func  getKeyFromLocation(location : CGPoint) -> String{
    var keysLocation   = [String: CGPoint]()
    keysLocation["q"] = CGPoint(x: 29, y: 29)
    keysLocation["w"] = CGPoint(x: 68, y: 29)
    keysLocation["e"] = CGPoint(x: 107, y: 29)
    keysLocation["r"] = CGPoint(x: 146, y: 29)
    keysLocation["t"] = CGPoint(x: 185, y: 29)
    keysLocation["y"] = CGPoint(x: 224, y: 29)
    keysLocation["u"] = CGPoint(x: 263, y: 29)
    keysLocation["i"] = CGPoint(x: 302, y: 29)
    keysLocation["o"] = CGPoint(x: 351, y: 29)
    keysLocation["p"] = CGPoint(x: 390, y: 29)
    keysLocation["a"] = CGPoint(x: 60, y: 80)
    keysLocation["s"] = CGPoint(x: 99, y: 80)
    keysLocation["d"] = CGPoint(x: 138, y: 80)
    keysLocation["f"] = CGPoint(x: 177, y: 80)
    keysLocation["g"] = CGPoint(x: 216, y: 80)
    keysLocation["h"] = CGPoint(x: 255, y: 80)
    keysLocation["j"] = CGPoint(x: 294, y: 80)
    keysLocation["k"] = CGPoint(x: 333, y: 80)
    keysLocation["l"] = CGPoint(x: 372, y: 80)
    keysLocation["z"] = CGPoint(x: 99, y: 140)
    keysLocation["x"] = CGPoint(x: 138, y: 140)
    keysLocation["c"] = CGPoint(x: 177, y: 140)
    keysLocation["v"] = CGPoint(x: 216, y: 140)
    keysLocation["b"] = CGPoint(x: 255, y: 140)
    keysLocation["n"] = CGPoint(x: 294, y: 140)
    keysLocation["m"] = CGPoint(x: 333, y: 140)

    var selectedkeycode = ""
    var minDistance = CGFloat(1000.0)

    for (keycode, point) in keysLocation {
        let distance = hypot(location.x - point.x, location.y - point.y)
        if(distance < minDistance ){
            minDistance = distance
            selectedkeycode = keycode
        }

    }

    print(minDistance)

    if(minDistance > CGFloat(50.0)){
        return ""
    }
    else{
        return selectedkeycode
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just simply cannot.

It would be a huge security risks if developers and hence apps would have access to the users passcode. Even if you could listen to keyboard notifications about key hits (which as far as I'm concerned is not possible) using a private API, your app would never make it to the AppStore, it would get rejected.

You can only receive information about key hits outside your application if you make your own keyboard, but even then, the system uses the default keyboard for all passwords and the passcode.

Comment: Actually the app is for research and will not going to be published to appstore

Comment: Even if it won't be published, as far as I'm concerned, there's no private API you could use to achieve this. The only method I know of that managed to break an iPhone's passcode was using motion sensors and machine learning, you can read about it [here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/04/12/researchers-demonstrate-passcode-detection-method-that-uses-your-phones-motion-sensors/)